# Are SDS drills metric, standard or all the same?

Tags: drill

Can I buy [SDS drills](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drill_bit_shank#SDS_shank) (or à drill machine) in the USA and use it with an European bought machine (or drills)? 
Is the SDS "connection" the same in Europe as it is in the US?

Sorry for the language, I hope you understand

Comment: Are you asking if SDS style bits sold in the US are the same as SDS style bits in Europe?

Comment: Hello. I want to by a machine in US and wonder if the drills from europe will work with a machine from US. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are three different SDS sizes: SDS plus, SDS top and SDS max.  You must match your tool type to the bits.  Within a given tool type (SDS plus, say), the tool side is the same.

They are available in both inch and metric sizes (on the cutting end).

[Wikipedia article on SDS shanks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drill_bit_shank#SDS_shank)

SDS-plus, SDS-Top and SDS-max. respectively:

[image: SDS-plus]  [image: SDS top]  [image: SDS max]

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer, I really appreciate it Sir.

Answer (score 0):

The most common type I've seen is SDS-plus (incompatible with SDS-max etc). Since this system was invented by Bosch it is not a de-jure international standard of the sort overseen by a standards body. However, unlike DVD content producers, Bosch  don't seem to have any incentive to make incompatible SDS products for different regions of the world. So you're probably OK if you stick to SDS-plus tools.